# Deleting dynamically created textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Good Day Everyone.

I'm creating function in which i dynamically generate textbox depending on the selected value in the dropdown list.

Here's the code.

```
comboboxNameHolder = ((ComboBox)sender).Name;
string comboboxNoHolder =comboboxNameHolder.Replace("cbFunctionList", "");
comboboxNo = Int32.Parse(comboboxNoHolder);
funcSelected = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
for (int i = 0; i < optionList1.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    if (funcSelected == optionList1[i, 0])
    {
        funcNoOfFields = optionList1[i, 1];
    }
}

if (lineFieldController[comboboxNo, 1] == 0)
{
    fieldCounter = Int32.Parse(funcNoOfFields);
    lineFieldController[comboboxNo, 1] = fieldCounter;
    inputField1 = new TextBox[fieldCounter];
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCounter; i++)
    {
        btnAddField0.Visible = false;
        inputField = new TextBox();
        inputField.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25f);
        inputField.Size = new Size(75, 24);
        inputField.Location = new Point(positionController[comboboxNo, 0], positionController[comboboxNo, 1]);
        inputField.Name = "txtLine" + comboboxNo.ToString() + "Variable" + i.ToString();


        this.Controls.Add(inputField1[i]);
        positionController[comboboxNo, 0] += 81;
    }
}
```

Now I want in the same function when the `lineFieldController` is not equal to zero means that there are already created textbox in that line. When the user chooses another value in the dropdown list the number of fields will change by deleting the existing fields then creating new ones depending on the selected item.

How do I delete the textboxes I created?? I tried calling it by name but it doesn't work.

```
else
{
    for(int i = 0; i < lineFieldController[comboboxNo, 1]; i++)
    {
        string name = "txtLine" + comboboxNo.ToString() + "Variable" + i.ToString();
        TextBox tb = this.Controls.Find(name, true);
    }
}
```

Hoping for your kind response

Comment: *but it doesn't work* ... throws an exception? returns null? what's the problem? I cannot see any line of code to remove/dispose the controls. Are your expectation about name of controls is right? Did you check what are the name of controls that you have in Controls collection? Did you debugged the code?

Answer (score 0):

you can put all controls that you have created put them to the list and hold reference on controls were created at runtime.

like

```
public class Form1
{
List<Control> createdList = new List<Control>(); // class field

void combobox_SelectedIndexChanged()
{
            // removing controls were created before
            foreach (var created in createdList)
            {
              this.Controls.Remove(created);
              created.Dispose();
            }
            createdList.Clear(); // all created controls from previous index changed should be removed here

            // add each control you are creating to the createList additionally
            inputField1 = new TextBox[fieldCounter];
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldCounter; i++)
            {
                btnAddField0.Visible = false;
                inputField = new TextBox();
                createdList.Add(inputField); //store reference

/// skipping init code

                this.Controls.Add(inputField1[i]);
                positionController[comboboxNo, 0] += 81;
            }

}

}
```

another option is to add panel on the form as a placeholder for all controls are being created. You have to change `this.Controls.Add(inputField1[i]);` to the `panelCreated.Controls.Add(inputField1[i]);` 
Then you can grab all controls from the panel and remove them without name search like below

```
foreach (Control created in panelCreated.Controls)
  created.Dispose();
panelCreated.Controls.Clear();
```